# QT how to handle HDPI display issues?

Tags: c++, qt

I've been working on an existing QT project, but I'm having some issues related to `4k` displays. On a `1080p` monitor the GUI looks great, but if I connect a `4k` monitor to my computer and move my QT application to the `4k` monitor the icons size change and looks very small. It also happens if the GUI app is running directly on a `4k` display laptop. So it seems the problem is that I need to add some conditions to rescale the GUI. Searching the web I found that I can disable high DPI but it doesn't seem to work

```
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_DisableHighDpiScaling);
```

Has anyone faced something similar?

Comment: ***but if I connect a 4k monitor to my computer and move my QT application to the 4k monitor the icons size change and looks very small.*** I think its already disabled and you want to instead enable it.

Comment: Hi @drescherjm, yes I disabled the `HDPIScaling` because I always get the same result. I also tried to enable the HDPI but still getting the same.

Comment: With HDPI disabled I would expect your fonts and Icons to be small on the 4K display. With it enabled your GUI will scale.

Comment: @drescherjm if I use `QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);` only certain elements of the GUI are scaled correctly but the text looks very small. Any idea why it happens?

Comment: Which OS and which Qt version?  

There is a pretty decent explanation of high-dpi scaling in the docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/highdpi.html

Comment: Hi @ecloud, I'm using Windows 10 and  QT 5.15.10, I include `QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);` and `QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps);` in my code and there are some improvements, but some text labels and other components are very small. This is due to the QT version?

Comment: @ecloud, I figure out that with  `QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);` and `QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps);` icons and some elements are correctly scaled at 4K resolutions, but text of components such as combobox don't. could it be a problem related to layout managers?